# Output not getting printed in external text file

Tags: python-3.x

enter code here I want to get the output of the following code in an external text file. I am able to create a text file but the data of the console is not getting printed into the text file. Snippet of my code below:

```py
import subprocess
import os
from concurrent.futures import  ThreadPoolExecutor

print('maximum no of runs is 4')

number=int(input('enter your choice:'))

if number<=4:

        num=int(number)
        def sally():
            os.chdir(r"C:\Program Files\xxxx")
            subprocess.Popen(r"C:\Program Files\xxx\yy.exe")
            os.system('cmd /k "xxxxxx"')

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as e
            total_runs=num
            for i in range(total_runs):
                e.submit(sally)
                i=i+1
else:
    print('your choice is exceeding')
```

The code which i am trying to get the output stored in an external text file is :

```py
import subprocess  
import os  
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor  

if number <= 4:  

    num = int(number)
    def sally():
        os.chdir(r"C:\Program Files\xxxx")

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as e:
            total_runs = num
            for i in range(total_runs):
                output=subprocess.run([r"C:\Program Files\xxxx\xx.exe", 'b'])
                e.submit(sally)
                i = i + 1  

    log_file = open('testccc.txt', 'w')
    log_file.write(output)


for this i am getting below error:

   log_file = open('testccc.txt', 'w')
x64 6.4E03 cpus:4 128T f:110C2774C
Permission Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'testccc.txt' 



not sure if what i have written is correct or not or i have missed something which i am not able to figure it out. Can anyone help me with this
```

Comment: Where do you actually redirect the output? As well, I see two syntax errors in this code. Please post a [mre]

Comment: hello, i am trying to achieve something like this, i want to store the output of my code into some other external text file. I have tried but it is not working as expected. The output i can see on the console but i am the given getting error :     log_file = open('testccc.txt', 'w')
x64 6.4E03 cpus:4 128T f:110C2774C
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'testccc.txt'